# Java textfields with integrated increase/decrease arrows

Tags: java, scrollbar, textfield

I'm building a GUI that will be used for inputting data in a database. More specifically I want to submit songs. Among the columns of the songs table is the song duration. What I would like is the user to have the ability to type the minute or seconds value i.e **02** inside a textfield but also have the choice to increase or decrease this value with the use of buttons which will be integrated on the TextField, like I have seen in many applications. I believe VisualBasic had a similar controller called Textbox.ScrollBars.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a [jSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html).

Scrollbars are a different thing entirely.

Comment: Hi Tim B, first of all thanks for your answer,Yes from what I read this is exactly what I am looking for. Silly I am, I forgot to mention that we are using JavaFX for this project and from a small research I did in StackExchange for a JSpinner equivalent for JavaFX I saw that there is not a similar controller in Java at the moment. However I found some custom controllers created by some users.
Thank you very much again.